`operation not permitted` when logging artifacts with mlflow on mounted disk
I'm trying to log a python experiment with mlflow on a remote disk that I mount automatically in /etc/fstab (debian, smb). Logging params works perfectly fine, the artifact gets copied, but code throws an error about copying attributes of the artifact:
import mlflow # version==2.16.0
import os

mlflow.set_tracking_uri(os.environ["MLFLOW_DIR"])
mlflow.set_experiment("mlflow_bug")
mlflow.start_run()
mlflow.log_param("param1", 1)  # this gets logged
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("Hello world!")
mlflow.log_artifact("test.txt") # this gets copied, then error is thrown
mlflow.end_run()

gives me the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 7
      5 with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
      6     f.write("Hello world!")
----> 7 mlflow.log_artifact("test.txt")
      8 mlflow.end_run()

File ~/code/syn_decoder/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py:1123, in log_artifact(local_path, artifact_path, run_id)
   1095 """
   1096 Log a local file or directory as an artifact of the currently active run. If no run is
   1097 active, this method will create a new active run.
   (...)
   1120             mlflow.log_artifact(path)
   1121 """
   1122 run_id = run_id or _get_or_start_run().info.run_id
-> 1123 MlflowClient().log_artifact(run_id, local_path, artifact_path)

File ~/code/syn_decoder/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py:1923, in MlflowClient.log_artifact(self, run_id, local_path, artifact_path)
   1919 if run_id.startswith(TRACE_REQUEST_ID_PREFIX):
   1920     raise MlflowException(
   1921         f"Invalid run id: {run_id}. `log_artifact` run id must map to a valid run."
   1922     )
-> 1923 self._tracking_client.log_artifact(run_id, local_path, artifact_path)

File ~/code/syn_decoder/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py:822, in TrackingServiceClient.log_artifact(self, run_id, local_path, artifact_path)
    820     artifact_repo.log_artifacts(local_path, path_name)
    821 else:
--> 822     artifact_repo.log_artifact(local_path, artifact_path)

File ~/code/syn_decoder/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/local_artifact_repo.py:45, in LocalArtifactRepository.log_artifact(self, local_file, artifact_path)
     43     mkdir(artifact_dir)
     44 try:
---> 45     shutil.copy2(local_file, os.path.join(artifact_dir, os.path.basename(local_file)))
     46 except shutil.SameFileError:
     47     pass

File /usr/lib/python3.11/shutil.py:437, in copy2(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    435     dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
    436 copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
--> 437 copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    438 return dst

File /usr/lib/python3.11/shutil.py:376, in copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    374     st = lookup("stat")(src, follow_symlinks=follow)
    375 mode = stat.S_IMODE(st.st_mode)
--> 376 lookup("utime")(dst, ns=(st.st_atime_ns, st.st_mtime_ns),
    377     follow_symlinks=follow)
    378 # We must copy extended attributes before the file is (potentially)
    379 # chmod()'ed read-only, otherwise setxattr() will error with -EACCES.
    380 _copyxattr(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow)

PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

I'm executing this code as a user being part of a group that has read/write access to the logging folder. The test.txt file get copied, but then the error is thrown.
> ls -l $MLFLOW_DIR/940396422779777099/487c714b29d441e1af3e3b962b108afc/artifacts/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root group 12 Sep 12 14:17 test.txt

What am I doing wrong ?
